# C# how to add inheritance in my hotel management system

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

i want to add inheritance in my hotel management system  and more classes any ideas ?
iam working on console application and if any one can give me more to add to this program ill be thankfull

program aims at reproducing a basic hotel room reservation scheme. After an instance of hotel number is created, by calling the checkIn() method, the program checks if there are rooms available, and if so it reserves the room.

However, it doesn't work if, after allocating all the rooms, someone checks out from one room (via checkOut() method), e.g. room number 1, and then tries to check in into that room. The issue occurs when checkIn() calls hasRoomsAvailable() method, which in such a case returns false instead of true, due to the fact that currentRoomNumber is 5.

```
using System;

namespace HotelManagement
{
    //otel sınıfı
    public class Hotel
    {
        private bool[] available;
        private int totalNumberOfRooms;
        private int currentRoomNumber;

        // oda sayısını bilirleyecek
        private Hotel(int totalNumberOfRooms)
        {
            this.totalNumberOfRooms = totalNumberOfRooms;
            available = new bool[totalNumberOfRooms];

            for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfRooms; i++)
                available[i] = true;
        }

        //Returns true if room is available
        private bool hasRoomsAvailable()
        {
            if (currentRoomNumber < totalNumberOfRooms &&
                available[currentRoomNumber])
                return available[currentRoomNumber];
            else
                return false;
        }

        //Time Complexity: O(1)

        //en azından bir oda olup olmadığını kontrol eder ve rezerv eder
        private int checkIn()
        {
            if (hasRoomsAvailable())
            {
                available[currentRoomNumber] = false;
                return ++currentRoomNumber;
            }
            else
                return -1;
        }
        

        //Check out method
        private void checkOut(int roomNumber)
        {
            if (roomNumber <= totalNumberOfRooms && roomNumber != -1)
            {
                if (available[roomNumber - 1] == false)
                {
                    available[roomNumber - 1] = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Check out oda: {0}", roomNumber);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("geçersiz Check Out : {0}", roomNumber);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("yanlış oda numarası: {0}", roomNumber);
        }
        //Time Complexity: O(1)

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create an instance of 5 odalı bir otel
            Hotel hotel = new Hotel(5);
            int roomNum = -1;

            if (hotel.hasRoomsAvailable())
            {
                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("tahsis edilen oda: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("tahsis edilen oda: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("tahsis edilen oda: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("tahsis edilen oda: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("tahsis edilen oda: {0}", roomNum);
            }

            hotel.checkOut(1);
            roomNum = hotel.checkIn();

            Console.WriteLine("tahsis edilen oda budur: {0}", roomNum);

            //pause program output on console
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to add inheritance? The FCoI principle says: "favor composition over inheritance".

Comment: Well, inheritance assumes you even **have** some behaviour that can be inheritaed to sub-classes. Currently it´s completely unclear what that behaviour and the appropriate sub-classes should be. Make one step back and draw your class-structure on a paper: which objects do you need? Which properties should they have? What functionality do they provide? How do they relate to one another? This is less a *programming*-question, but more a *design*-problem.

Comment: BTW hotel management is really crazy. You need to be able to over-book the hotel, i.e. reserve rooms that don't exist. This sometimes requires great diplomatic skills from the receptionists: if not enough visits were cancelled, they need to move guests to a different hotel because no rooms are free.

Comment: First of all, you say your class has a bug - so is your question about that primarily ? Presumably you've stepped through the code in order to find what the issue is ? Why are you bringing up this other issue to do with inheritance ?

Comment: If you expand your model you might consider there are some attributes that all rooms have and some behaviours that all rooms share, whereas there are types of room that have extra facilities and uses, like adjoining rooms, as an example.

Answer (score 2):

As a general approach, I recommend programming exactly what a human would do (without a PC). Would they have a sheet of paper where they write down the `currentRoomNumber`? Probably not. Would they have a table with all rooms? Yes. Would they add a cross into that table when someone checks in and erase it when someone checks out? Yes. How would they find a free room?

There is no inheritance needed to fix the problem you have. You are trying to assign rooms in the order of their room number. You keep track of that with the `currentRoomNumber`. That's not how it works. One assigns rooms by number of beds, size in square meters, price, floor, ...

Instead, you should walk through the array `bool available[]` and find one that is `false`. Since this looks like study or homework, I'll leave the implementation for you. Hints: use a `for` loop, keep track of the index and `break` out of the loop.

---

For object orientated design, you can do the following:

- write down sentences of what it means to manage a hotel
- identify nouns, they will become classes
- identify verbs, they will become methods
- check for synonyms, e.g. "room" = "apartment" or "checkout" = "leave" and choose one word only
- assign the verbs to the nouns
- think about which verb needs which information. That will become parameters, if the information is not known by *noun* himself.

---

Your main() method looks much like a test. Read about "Unit testing" and separate the testing code from your hotel management application.

Comment: I really like the abstract OOP-recipie on the bottom of your answer. If only you´d provided that some years earlier to me :D

Answer (score 0):

In case you're actually interested in why your code isn't working - when you check out you don't set the variable `currentRoomNumber` to the room number you've just checked out. Adding this line in your checkOut method fixes that:

```
                available[roomNumber - 1] = true;
                currentRoomNumber = roomNumber - 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Check out oda: {0}", roomNumber);
```